# Grails findBy returns (unsaved) object causing null issue with render()

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to render a GSP template as a PDF and email it, but I'm running into a weird issue. I used Grails `findBy*` method to get my data,

```
def fax(Integer id) {
    def transcriptInstance = Transcript.findById(id)
    def userInstance = User.findById(transcriptInstance.submitter)

    def m = [userInstance: userInstance, transcriptInstance: transcriptInstance]

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "/transcript/_pdf", model: m)

    mailService.sendMail {
        to <my email> // for testing
        from <my email> // for testing
        subject "PDF Attachment";
        attachBytes "transcript.pdf", "application/pdf", bytes.toByteArray()
        body "PDF attachment"
    }
}
```

but the user instance returns as `User : (unsaved)` and I'm getting the error `Cannot invoke method render() on null object` on the line `ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: "/transcript/_pdf", model: m)`. The user is definitely saved in the database and this is the first time I've run across this. Any idea what's going wrong?

EDIT:

This code now produces a pdf, but I cannot get it to send via the mailService.

```
def fax(Integer id) {
    def transcriptInstance  = Transcript.findById(id)
    def userInstance = User.findById(transcriptInstance.submitter)

    def m = [userInstance: userInstance, transcriptInstance: transcriptInstance]

    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfBytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: '/transcript/pdf', model: m)
    new File('test.pdf').withOutputStream { 
        it.write pdfBytes.toByteArray()
    }

    mailService.sendMail {
        multipart true
        to <my email> // for testing
        from <my email> // for testing
        subject "PDF Attachment";
        attachBytes "transcript.pdf", "application/pdf", <WHAT DO I PUT HERE?>
        body "PDF attachment"
    }
}
```

I've tried a few things in the  spot, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this user instance unsaved when you execute `User.findById(transcriptInstance.submitter)` or it become unsaved later? (maybe it becomes dirty f.e. in `pdfRenderingService.render()`)

Comment: The user is saved and in the database at the time of `.findById()`. I can access any fields I want debugging with `println "userInstance id: " + userInstance.id`.

Comment: I believe it may be an issue of me not instantiating `pdfRenderingService` correctly. Do I need a specific import at the top of the controller? I just have `def pdfRenderingService` outside of all actions and `compile "org.grails.plugins:rendering:1.0.0"` within BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: I'm not asking about userInstance's fields from db, I'm asking on which stage `userInstance.isDirty() == true`.

Comment: Michal, see my edit.

Comment: try print "${userInstance.errors.allErrors}" right under where you have referenced it - I have seen that error only when there has been errors saving else where and you need to find out what validation is making it fail from saving. That how ever does not answer the segment of error related to pdf which I would have thought has nothing to do with the db - so unelss there is other things going on

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your ByteArrayOutputStream you can call toByteArray() to get the bytes needed by the mailService.

```
def fax(Integer id) {
    def transcriptInstance  = Transcript.findById(id)
    def userInstance = User.findById(transcriptInstance.submitter)

    def m = [userInstance: userInstance, transcriptInstance: transcriptInstance]

    ByteArrayOutputStream pdfBytes = pdfRenderingService.render(template: '/transcript/pdf', model: m)

    mailService.sendMail {
        multipart true
        to <my email> // for testing
        from <my email> // for testing
        subject "PDF Attachment";
        attachBytes "transcript.pdf", "application/pdf", pdfBytes.toByteArray()
        body "PDF attachment"
    }
}
```